# PHP calculating cost of hire

Tags: php

My form contains two time inputs for the start time and end time.

I want to validate them so that the times must either be on the hour or half past the hour. 

I also want to take the times, work out how many half hours there are between them and multiply this by a number to get the cost of hire.

I have no idea how i would go about this.

Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems there.

1. Valid times
2. Calculations

For the 1. problem, I'd suggest 3 dropdown-menus for one time. One for the hours, one for the minutes (00 or 30) and one for am or pm. To differ between am and pm, you could also use radiobuttons.

For the calcuation it is quite simple.
We have 2 times, e.g. 8:30 am and 4:30 pm.

1. Get the two times
2. If one time is pm, add 12 to the hour
3. Divide the hours of both times through 2.
4. If the minutes are equal to 30, add 1 to the time
5. Subtract time 2 minus time 1.

For the example:

```
8:30 am - 4:30 pm
8/2+1 = 4
(4+12)/2+1 =9
9-4 =5 -> 5 half hours between
Multiply with cost factor and you are done.
```

In PHP I'd attempt this:

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['submit']){
  $pm1 = $_POST['pm1']; //boolean, true if time 1 is pm
  $pm2 = $_POST['pm2'];//same for time 2
  $h1 = !$pm1 ? $_POST['hours1'] : $_POST['hours1']+12 ; //if time 1 pm -> hours1+12
  $h2 = !$pm1 ? $_POST['hours2'] : $_POST['hours2']+12 ; //same here for hours 2
  $m1 = $_POST['minutes1'];
  $m2 = $_POST['minutes2'];
  $h1 = $m1=="00" ? $h1 : $h1+1; //if minutes are 00 -> hours1 +1
  $h2 = $m2=="00" ? $h2 : $h2+1;
  $factor = 10,5; //cost factor

  $time = $h2-$h1
  $cost = $time*$factor; // cost
}
?>
```